# table float in 2 columns environment

Tags: latex

I want to put a basic table into a 2-columns document.

I saw that instead of:

```
\begin{table}
   enter code here
\end{table}
```

we should use:

```
\begin{table*}
   enter code here
\end{table*}
```

but it is not working.

If anyone has an idea, thanks in advance! Below a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% fake text
\usepackage{multicol}% enable writing in 2 columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{7mm}% separation between the two columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}% width of the separation lign(comment if not wanted)

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \begin{table*}[t]
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            A & b\\
            c & d
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the document class is important.
If I change

```
 article -> scrartcl
```

I can use the

```
\captionof{table}{my caption}
```

without using the `table` environment.
But I don't know if it is the right way to do it.

Comment: `\captionof` is a macro from the `caption` package. if you load the package, you can also use it in article class

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ok thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Floats and marginpars are not allowed inside `multicols` environment. Also, `table*` would be page wide. If you comment the `table*` environment, you get the `tabular` in the second column:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% fake text
\usepackage{multicol}% enable writing in 2 columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{7mm}% separation between the two columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}% width of the separation lign(comment if not wanted)

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]

%\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  A & b\\
  c & d
\end{tabular}
%\end{table*}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Rather, you can nest the `tabular` inside a `center` environment and, if you need, use the package [`caption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) to label and reference your `tabular` although it's not a float.